# cakephp3 iterate hasMany associated entities

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

We are using the new cakePHP ORM and I have some issues understanding the way the new ORM works when dealing with hasMany associations.

E.g. We have a Table called "Users" which has a hasMany relation to another Table "UsersAbsences". The definition and handling itself works fine. We have defined the Table-Objects and the Entities.

```
$this->addAssociations([
'hasMany' => [
    'UsersAbsences' => [
        'className' => 'UsersAbsences',
        'propertyName' => 'absences',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
    ]
]);
```

Within our UsersTable we've created a custom method which retrieves details to one User, using the QueryBuilders ->contain Method to fetch the hasMany-associated "UsersAbsences" defined by property "absence". We're setting the view-variable $user to work with the Entity in the template: Works fine.

```
...
$users->contain(['UsersAbsences',...]);
...
```

Now the part that puzzles me:
The Object-type of $user is "UserEntity". When I now iterate through the $user->absences... i always get CakeEntity objects, not (as I would expect) AbsenceEntity-objects.

Problem: I would like to implement a custom method in the UserAbsence-Entity which I would like to call in the template when iterating through each Absence of the user.

When using the ->contain Method for associations attached with "belongsTo", I get the correct Entity-Class.

Someone an idea how to deal with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mind your terminology, entity classes do not have a `Entity` suffix, this makes your question a little confusing, as one might think that you've named all your classes incorrectly! Please use actual, ideally [**fully qualified classnames**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php) in your questions!

That being said, by default the name of the corresponding entity is figured from the table class name, that is, the singular name without `Table` suffix. So, for `UsersTable` it's `User`, and for `UsersAbsencesTable` it would be `UsersAbsence`, not just `Absence`.

So, renaming your `Absence` entity file/class to `UsersAbsence` should fix the problem. Alternatively you can manually define the entity class a table should use by specifying it via [**`Table::entityClass()`**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#customizing-the-entity-class-a-table-uses).

See also

- **[Cookbook > ... CakePHP Conventions > File and Class Name Conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html#file-and-class-name-conventions)**
- **[Cookbook > ... ORM > Table Objects > Customizing the Entity Class a Table Uses](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#customizing-the-entity-class-a-table-uses)**

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice, i was afraid it had to do with the naming of the files.